# What to do with topics in documentation that seem to belong in Q&A?

Tags: discussion, documentation

This is a [current topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/unity3d/2304/why-is-it-that-when-i-derive-from-monobehaviour-i-dont-have-to-override-awake) in documentation

> ### Why is it that when I derive from MonoBehaviour, I don't have to override Awake, Start, Update and other methods?

with the corresponding *example*

> The reason you do not have to override Awake, Start, Update and other method is because they are not virtual methods defined in a base class.
>
> The first time your script gets accessed, the scripting runtime looks through the script to see if some methods are defined. If they are, that information is cached and the methods are added to their respective list. These lists are then simply looped through at different times.
>
> The reason these methods are not virtual is because of performance. If all the scripts would have Awake, Start, OnEnable, OnDisable, Update, LateUpdate, and FixedUpdate, then these would all be added to their lists what would mean that all these methods get executed. Normally this wouldn't be a big problem, however, all these method calls are from the native side (C++) to the managed side (C#) which comes with a performance cost.
>
> Now imagine this, all these methods are in their lists and some/most of them might not even have an actual method body. This would mean that there is a huge amount of performance wasted on calling methods that do not even do anything. To prevent this, Unity opted out of using virtual methods and made a messaging system that makes sure that these methods only get called when they are actually defined, saving unnecessary method calls.
>
> You can read more on the matter on an Unity blog over here: 10000 Update() Calls and more on IL2CPP over here: An Introduction to IL2CPP Internals

This seems to belong in Q&A rather than Documentation?

Should just click *delete*? I'd prefer not to delete someone work. Maybe there should be a *move to Q&A* button? Maybe I should encourage moving it Q&A and leave it for someone else to delete?

Thoughts?

How will we prevent documentation from becoming a mess of Q&A in general? Or maybe I shouldn't be preventing it and this is a totally valid use?

Comment: It's kind of funny: one of the given reasons for creating Docs was that people weren't using self-answered Q&A, and now that it exists people are putting self-answered Q&A in Docs.

Comment: Ha, that is actually a topic I proposed. I should perhaps not have phrased the title as a question. It is however a somewhat poorly documented topic (you have to go to blog posts rather than official documentation) and a source of frequent confusion and misconception. So I thought it would be an interesting topic to include in the doc. I haven't actively participated in the whole doc setup yet, so I'll let those who are more active give their views on this.

Comment: I see the title has now been edited. I would personally say that in that form it should be find for doc.

Comment: That wasn't the type of example I was expecting. I've seen a 1 rep user *repeatedly* trying to ask their question on Documentation. *sigh*

Comment: Just changing the title doesn't seem like enough to make it fit in documentation. At best it seems like it belongs as a *remark* under the `MonoBehaviour` topic?

Comment: It might be a too specific topic, not sure though (don't know much about Mono). Anyway, topic titles shouldn't be formulated as questions but as statements.